# "Attempt to index nil with 'stat'" How to fix that ? (Roblox)

Tags: lua, comments, roblox, nul

**PROBLEM:**

Hi The output says:

> Players.username.PlayerGui.GameGui.GameController:63: attempt to index nil with 'Stats'

This is my code:

> local maxTowers = towerToSpawn.Stats.MaxPlaced.Value

> local PlacedTowers = towerToSpawn.Stats.Placed.Value

What the problem ?

**CONTEXT:**

I make a tower defense and I want to restrict the number of each type of tower that can be placed.

ps :

> local towerToSpawn =
> ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Towers"):FindFirstChild(name):Clone()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jefb.jpg)

Comment: One scenario where the result of Clone could be nil is when the Archivable flag is set to false, can you check that? https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Instance#Clone

Comment: I check that but the archivable index is set to true

Comment: Hmm, and `towerToSpawn` is definitely within scope and executed before the other two lines of code?

Comment: Hi thx for your answer but I succeeded without knowing how I just continued the script to do something else before finding an answer and now it works thank you for trying to help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.